# How to use the UseState hook on an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a 10*10 grid, each cell having its own unique id/index. I loop over them and render the grid on the page. then I calculate the coordinates corresponding to each cell. What I'm trying to do next, is add an event listener so whenever an individual cell gets clicked, its background color changes to green (according to its coordinates which we calculated before); however, the background color does not seem change on click:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXnRA.png)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // dynamically set the grid size
  const [grid] = useState(10);

  // here's my problem, I can't figure out how to change the background color
  // of a cell using the UseState hook
  const [isGreen] = useState({});

  // get the x, y coordinates
  const getCoordinates = (id) => {
    const y =
      id % grid !== 0 ? Math.floor(id / grid) : Math.floor((id - 1) / grid);
    const x = id % grid !== 0 ? id - Math.floor(id / grid) * grid : grid;

    return {
      x: x,
      y: y + 1
    };
  };

  // make them readable e.g: {x: 1, y: 2} -> (1, 2)
  const readableCoordinates = (obj) => {
    return `(${obj.x}, ${obj.y})`;
  };

  // not sure if this is the right way to do it
  const makeItGreen = (x, y) => {
    isGreen[`(${x}, ${y})`] = true;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My Coordinates</h1>
      <div className="grid">
        {[...Array(100)].map((e, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              style={
                isGreen[
                  `(${getCoordinates(i + 1).x}, ${getCoordinates(i + 1).y})`
                ] && {
                  backgroundColor: 'green'
                }
              }
              onClick={() => {
                makeItGreen(
                  getCoordinates(i + 1).x,
                  getCoordinates(i + 1).y
                );
              }}
            >
              {readableCoordinates(getCoordinates(i + 1))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please read a bit more about [useState](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#usestate) usage in docs. It seems like you are using it wrong

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).